# C#, WIF, WCF -> Generation of the proxy when adding a second reference

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, wif, claims-based-identity

I've implemented a c# solution that contain a custom STS, a WCF services and a simple console application to interact with bot servers.

STS make an authentication based on username and password.  There's the web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

<configSections>
<section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
</configSections>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<appSettings>
<add key="IssuerName" value="SecurityTokenService" />
<add key="SigningCertificateName" value="CN=STSTestCert"/>
<add key="EncryptingCertificateName" value="CN=STSTestCert"/>
</appSettings>

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
    <service name="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceContract" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="Username/IWSTrust13" binding="ws2007HttpBinding" contract="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrust13SyncContract" bindingConfiguration="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration"/>
    <host>
        <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:9090/Service.svc"/>
        </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</services>
<bindings>
    <ws2007HttpBinding>
    <binding name="ws2007HttpBindingConfiguration">
        <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType ="None">
            <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
        </transport>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false"/>
        </security>
    </binding>
    </ws2007HttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <serviceCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="STSTestCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" />
        <issuedTokenAuthentication allowUntrustedRsaIssuers="true"/>
        <clientCertificate>
            <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"/>
        </clientCertificate>
        </serviceCredentials>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
    <securityTokenHandlers>
    <remove type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add type="SecurityTokenService.CustomUserNamePasswordTokenHandler" />
    </securityTokenHandlers>
    <certificateValidation certificateValidationMode="None" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
    <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://localhost:1996/STSService.svc"/>
    </audienceUris>
</service>
</microsoft.identityModel>
</configuration>
```

After that I've added an STS reference for two web services on my WCf service.  There's the web.config :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="microsoft.identityModel" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.MicrosoftIdentityModelSection, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="FederationMetadataLocation" value="http://localhost:1996/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml" />
      </appSettings>
      <connectionStrings />
      <location path="FederationMetadata">
        <system.web>
          <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
          </authorization>
        </system.web>
      </location>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <authentication mode="Windows" />
        <pages>
          <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
          </controls>
        </pages>
      </system.web>
      <system.web.extensions>
        <scripting>
          <webServices>
          </webServices>
        </scripting>
      </system.web.extensions>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <service name="ClaimsAwareService.Service" behaviorConfiguration="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceBehavior">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/Service.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" contract="ClaimsAwareService.IService" bindingConfiguration="ClaimsAwareService.IService_ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
          <service name="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceTest" behaviorConfiguration="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceTestBehavior">
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/ServiceTest.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" contract="ClaimsAwareService.IServiceTest" bindingConfiguration="ClaimsAwareService.IServiceTest_ws2007FederationHttpBinding" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceBehavior">
              <federatedServiceHostConfiguration name="ClaimsAwareService.Service" />
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
              <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate findValue="AD4437492F905F0C462C099F814F99C7AD38F3F5" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
              </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceTestBehavior">
              <federatedServiceHostConfiguration name="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceTest" />
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
              <serviceCredentials>
                <serviceCertificate findValue="AD4437492F905F0C462C099F814F99C7AD38F3F5" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
              </serviceCredentials>
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
          <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="federatedServiceHostConfiguration" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Configuration.ConfigureServiceHostBehaviorExtensionElement, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
          </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
        <bindings>
          <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
            <binding name="ClaimsAwareService.IService_ws2007FederationHttpBinding">
              <security mode="Message">
                <message>
                  <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/mex" />
                  <claimTypeRequirements>
                    <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" isOptional="true" />
                    <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" isOptional="true" />
                  </claimTypeRequirements>
                </message>
              </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="ClaimsAwareService.IServiceTest_ws2007FederationHttpBinding">
              <security mode="Message">
                <message>
                  <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/mex" />
                  <claimTypeRequirements>
                    <add claimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" isOptional="true" />
                    <add claimType="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" isOptional="true" />
                  </claimTypeRequirements>
                </message>
              </security>
            </binding>
          </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <microsoft.identityModel>
        <service name="ClaimsAwareService.Service">
          <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost:1996/STS/" realm="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/Service" requireHttps="false" />
          </federatedAuthentication>
          <audienceUris>
            <add value="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/Service.svc" />
          </audienceUris>
          <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <trustedIssuers>
              <add thumbprint="AD4437492F905F0C462C099F814F99C7AD38F3F5" name="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc" />
            </trustedIssuers>
          </issuerNameRegistry>
        </service>
        <service name="ClaimsAwareService.ServiceTest">
          <federatedAuthentication>
            <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost:1996/STS/" realm="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/ServiceTest" requireHttps="false" />
          </federatedAuthentication>
          <audienceUris>
            <add value="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/ServiceTest.svc" />
          </audienceUris>
          <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
            <trustedIssuers>
              <add thumbprint="AD4437492F905F0C462C099F814F99C7AD38F3F5" name="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc" />
            </trustedIssuers>
          </issuerNameRegistry>
        </service>
      </microsoft.identityModel>
    </configuration>
```

Finally I've added Service and ServiceTest as a service referonce into my console application.  Service has been added without any problem and everything works fine but when I've added the ServiceTest, I can't see any endpoint for this service into app.config.  There's my app.config :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                        openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                            enabled="false" />
                        <security mode="Message">
                            <message algorithmSuite="Default" issuedKeyType="SymmetricKey"
                                negotiateServiceCredential="true">
                                <issuer address="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/Username/IWSTrust13"
                                    binding="ws2007HttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/Username/IWSTrust13">
                                    <identity>
                                        <certificate encodedValue="AwAAAAEAAAAUAAAArUQ3SS+QXwxGLAmfgU+Zx6048/UgAAAAAQAAAOgCAAAwggLkMIIBzKADAgECAhA3U0RwmaYcvENVelL9IMxBMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMBYxFDASBgNVBAMTC1NUU1Rlc3RDZXJ0MB4XDTExMTIyMTE2NTU0MloXDTEyMTIyMDIyNTU0MlowFjEUMBIGA1UEAxMLU1RTVGVzdENlcnQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCu2TXGBpKsTmasogT3ANb/PxGkMwQYVS7J7qLeANEmRjvdmozVmy+BMz7Sktw5LpeH+7rpiWWIT1e+BE5RFzyfSmB2CAnsqDrbRO3snzxEYKn4RZAF29YYkhaxx2xPaczGn4M4jceGImV2apsS8NSP6PXY5/9ZZHlWWcvbltz5c76+EbNqeihVh4FH3Nyql7h5kv/lD8Zmn3SBhRe/w3PhOAieT57RXL3OeIIxK/xVLe0+S/DPWLSy6FuejuiYY/ZoVVau3uCTh2Fr5o7/e9cbn4c85XnHZas4osEBoGgfbxKbvEDofbEwVr9g/oyfFA/lxLlqA4Mkn6Qi/+qCicCDAgMBAAGjLjAsMAsGA1UdDwQEAwIE8DAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUfJL72ZCFE8JZK3Xpk5ToMJq6N9swDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADggEBAIV4Cgtk4OtUXNTzKqsebA2BUyEbNNTo5cgDqBH7be6AChKaPMEK/PuV+Potv0iDQq1ONnKXgD76V63Lu5KQHLd+UoFrL8LMixWJhNR3scqKYNSjwlhcL/7DxwBGil1hnTralTehsWIV4JlMF9gkcwzMu1gzlYRJe8BAFmEs+zJwdSSU4VPy/sQPcDZ2U7MErMctghIPpRlTCSS2Jn/+fzRdr2e6Dy5cbghlndr0Bj0q5edLqlA5C5OwitLljtCQPRQwZTqvhlQU1h3EXMOMPoqT32pIvdC2g8TzPZz+eW51DXUTfAunnfNeddQvoKBTxbWkqeGNchQb+duGT5MeR1k=" />
                                    </identity>
                                </issuer>
                                <issuerMetadata address="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/mex" />
                                <tokenRequestParameters>
                                    <trust:SecondaryParameters xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                        <trust:KeyType xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512/SymmetricKey</trust:KeyType>
                                        <trust:KeySize xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">256</trust:KeySize>
                                        <trust:Claims Dialect="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity"
                                            xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">
                                            <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"
                                                Optional="true" xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                            <wsid:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"
                                                Optional="true" xmlns:wsid="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity" />
                                        </trust:Claims>
                                        <trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p</trust:KeyWrapAlgorithm>
                                        <trust:EncryptWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptWith>
                                        <trust:SignWith xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1</trust:SignWith>
                                        <trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#</trust:CanonicalizationAlgorithm>
                                        <trust:EncryptionAlgorithm xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc</trust:EncryptionAlgorithm>
                                    </trust:SecondaryParameters>
                                </tokenRequestParameters>
                            </message>
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>
                <ws2007HttpBinding>
                    <binding name="http://localhost:1996/Service.svc/Username/IWSTrust13"
                        closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                        sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false"
                        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
                        <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                        <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                            enabled="false" />
                        <security mode="Message">
                            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                                realm="" />
                            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                                algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                        </security>
                    </binding>
                </ws2007HttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
                <endpoint address="http://localhost:2059/ClaimsAwareService/Service.svc"
                    binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService"
                    contract="ServiceReference.IService" name="WS2007FederationHttpBinding_IService">
                    <identity>
                        <certificate encodedValue="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" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

My question : Why my endpoint ServiceTest is not generated by the Http proxy?  Is that I missed something regarding configuration of my STS and/or WCF server?